# How would it be sorted in alphabetical order inside tuple in dictionary?

Tags: python

I sorted a dictionary by value like `sorted(myDict.items(), key = operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)` and now I want to sort alphabet comparing integers those are similar in every tuple. That means I expect to get

`('A', 2),
 ('H', 2),
 ('N', 2),
 ('U', 2),
 ('W', 2),`

The below code I would like to modify

`[('S', 7),
 ('T', 6),
 ('I', 5),
 ('E', 4),
 ('O', 3),
 ('H', 2),
 ('A', 2),
 ('U', 2),
 ('N', 2),
 ('W', 2),
 ('C', 1),
 ('M', 1),
 ('Q', 1),
 ('Y', 1)]`

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you want to first consider the value and then the keys as sorting key :

```
sorted(myDict.items(), key = lambda x: (x[1], ord(x[0])))
```